# html 5 video using video.js doesn't play on iphone/ipad and in ie appears as a thumbnail to play

Tags: iphone, html, internet-explorer, video, jquery-jscrollpane

I using html5 video with the video.js and hosting the js and css on my server rather than linking to their site. The video re-sizes to two different sizes one for screens >1500px and one for screens <1500px. This is working fine in safari and firefox, chrome for mac and firefox for pc. I have also set the video formats in my .htaccess file.

I have 2 issues.
1. It won't play on iphone/ipad. I have put in the direct path to the video on my iphone and it plays fine so I don't think it is an issue with how it was encoded. But just in case I exported a mov file from flash and then used miro to convert it to a mp4. Also I have tried with and without the poster been defined as I read that could cause issues. Have just discovered if i removed the jscrollpane jquery the video will play on iphone/ipad but that does create issues with the horizontal scroll on the site. I have left the reference in to the jscrollpane by kevin luck incase someone so hopefully it makes it easier to figure out what is going on.

1. On a pc using IE the video works but the size is a thumbnail and wont filled the space.

HAVE NOW SORTED OUT MY ISSUES - JUST ADDED IMPORTANT AFTER THE WIDTH AND THAT FIXED THE IE ISSUE OF THE SIZE OF THE VIDEO.

Comment: there are a lot of errors in your page it's hard to instantly distinguish what could be the problem. Can you remove all of the 404 errors and repost or do an example over at jsfiddle?

Comment: so sorry about that - I blame very tired eyes/brain for not checking that all those errors where appearing. I have stripped all back and have discovered that 2 things. 1. there appears to be a conflict with jscrollpane and the video playing on the iphone - as soon as that reference is removed the video plays. Which is a problem as the whole site is build around the custom horizontal scrolling... not sure what to do there as that is beyond my coding capabilities - open to suggestions on where to start looking. Also 2. still the same issue in IE. Thanks for pulling up the 404 errors - has help